# How to pass a object* as a void*&?

Tags: c++, void, void-pointers

I have the following code :

```
void testCopy(){
   Balloon* b1=new Balloon(1,5,6,3);
   Balloon* b2=new Ballon(2,4,4,2);
   cpyBallon(b1,b2);
   assert(b1->getCenterx()==5);
   cout<<" cpyBalloon() OK!\n";
}
```

and the code for the cpyBalloon() is

```
void cpyBalloon(TCE& dest,TCE src){
    Balloon* b=(Balloon*) src;
    Balloon* d=new Balloon();
    *d=*b;
    dest=d;
}
```

where TCE if of type void*.
The problem is that i don't know how to pass the object b2 which is of type Balloon* as void*&. I keep getting the following error:

```
    ..\src\/Domain/BalloonTest.h:68:18: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'void*& {aka void*&}' from expression of type 'domain::Balloon*'
    ..\src\/Domain/Balloon.h:102:10: error: in passing argument 1 of 'void domain::delBalloon(void*&)'
```

I know that b2 is the argument with which I have the problem but I don't know how what to do to make it work.

Comment: Holyjesus terrible code.

Comment: @DeadMG Right? daknok writes better code. :Đ

Comment: You know that your `testCopy` code leaks memory? Specifically, it leaks 3 balloon objects -- two allocated in `testCopy` and one allocated in `cpyBalloon`. Of these, the one allocated in the first line seems the most severe leak, since it's already unreachable before the end of the `testCopy` function.

Comment: Yes I know it still has problems but first I want to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Terrible code? What's wrong with assigning a Balloon* to a TCE&? You can always create a conversion constructor or operator—or, even better, a TCE::operator= overload—to make that compile and do… well, almost anything you want. And cpyBallon is a great abbreviation for copyBalloon, since it saves two characters of typing, and they're two of the three O's, which makes it especially easy to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code states, you have a Balloon class. You've dynamically allocated memory for two Balloon instances and called their constructors, filling them in with respective data. Then, you stored the address of each of those objects into proper raw pointers.

This typedef:

```
typedef void* TCE; // why?
```

is pointless. A reference to a `void*` (`void*&`) is also pointless. Why? Because `void*` holds only one value - the first byte of a stream of bytes (their count is lost when you interpret anything as `void*`, that's because count is type-dependent). So, it is already a pointer. You're not passing an entire stream of bytes, just the address of the first byte. And then you further interpret it in the function as you'd like.

But in this  case, it's not necessary to interpret it as such. A reference, when analyzed from a really low level, is just a pointer in disguise and enables us to reap the benefits of pointers safely (without thinking about it too much). There's more to it, but for now, this is important.

You can either:

1. Create the instances on the stack (locally) and pass it in as a reference.
2. Create the instances on the heap and acquire memory addresses, pass them in and process further.
3. Or... You can take course of action 2 and cast them as `void*`, then undo the cast in the function (for whatever good that will do).

Observe first:

```
    Balloon b1(1,5,6,3);
    Balloon b2(2,4,4,2);

    cpyBalloon(b1, b2);

    void cpyBalloon(Balloon& dest, const Balloon& src) 
    {
        dest = src; // invokes the assignment copy operator (imp. generated)
    }
```

Observe second:

```
    Balloon* b1 = new Balloon(1,5,6,3);
    Balloon* b2 = new Balloon(2,4,4,2);

    cpyBalloon(b1, b2);

    void cpyBalloon(Balloon* dest, const Balloon* src) 
    {
        *dest = *src; // invokes the assignment copy operator (imp. generated)
    }
```

Observe third (dear lord...):

```
    Balloon* b1 = new Balloon(1,5,6,3);
    Balloon* b2 = new Balloon(2,4,4,2);

    cpyBalloon((void*)b1, (void*)b2);

    void cpyBalloon(void* dest, const Balloon* src) 
    {
        *(Balloon*)dest = *(const Balloon*)src; // oh god...
    }
```

You can also reinterpet_cast to circumvent all compiler help with type checking which is extremely dangerous and if you have to use it, you're either very wrong or have a really nasty problem (which could stem from your approach being *very wrong*). Notice the `const`ness around the source, that's good practice whenever you want something copied and undamaged.

Also note that there is a lot of memory management that arises in these situations, this is just a simple situation.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me a lot. I didn't quite understand void*. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an lvalue of type `T*` (where `T` is not `void`) as an argument of type `void *&`. This is not allowed by the language. Just because any data pointer type is convertible to `void *` does not mean that any data pointer type is convertible to `void *&`. These are completely different things.

If you really want to do this, you have to force the conversion to `void *&` by using `reinterpret_cast`. However, the manipulations that you seem to be trying to carry out don't really make much sense. Even if your code may be *forced* to "work" by using `reinterpret_cast`, it will still be a hack.

Comment: And in case it isn't clear, the reason "work" is in inverted commas is because the resulting code might appear to work, but isn't guaranteed to work by the standard. Of the things fighting against you the main one is the strict aliasing rules (which is a way of saying "the optimizer is allowed to break your code"). Also of theoretical interest is the fact that the representation of `object*` isn't required to be the same as the representation of `void*`, so reinterpreting an `object*&` as `void*&` is formally incorrect. When AndreyT says "it's a hack", he means "don't do it".